# Animating sprites, adding too images many to stage

Tags: javascript, animation, createjs

I've set up a script that animates an image across the canvas element.
What I'm trying to do is track the x of the image and when it gets to a certain point it spawns another image to animate, it seems to be creating too many images to the point where it crashes the browser any help?
The main parts of the code:

```
 function tick() {
     pauseTweens();

     for (var i = 0; i < linesArray.length; i++) {
         if (linesArray[i] >= 200 && linesArray[i] <= 210) {
             spawnSprite();
             linesArray = [];
         }
     }

     for (var i = items.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
         var item = items[i];
         console.log(item.x)
         if (item.x > stage.canvas.width) {
             stage.removeChild(item);
             items.splice(i, 1);
         }
     }

     stage.update();
 }
```

This is the function that Animates the sprite

```
function animate(asset, prop, val, duration) {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    var end = start + duration;
    var current = asset[prop];
    var distance = val - current;
    var step = function () {
        var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
        var progress = Math.min((duration - (end - timestamp)) / duration, 1);
        asset[prop] = current + (distance * progress);
        var a = Math.round(asset.x);
        linesArray.push(a)

        if (progress < 1) requestAnimationFrame(step);
    };

    return step();
};
```

This creates the sprite

```
 function spawnSprite() {
     linesArray = [];
     console.log("spawnSprite");
     spawnNow = false;
     var asset = buildSprite(sprite);
     animate(asset, 'x', -40, p.duration);
     animate(asset, 'y', 20, p.duration);
     animate(asset, 'alpha', 0, p.duration);
     animate(asset, 'scaleY', .2, p.duration);
     animate(asset, 'scaleX', .2, p.duration);
     items.push(asset)
 }
```

Comment: Please post a complete example with HTML.

Comment: Hi A.L thanks for your time, my question has changed, so I've posted a new question, with a fiddle -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32665908/animating-objects-to-a-specific-spot -- hope you can help